# Is a Spindown d20 still fair?

Tags: probability, dice

Is a Spindown d20 (numbers arranged consecutively around the instead of 21-sums arrangement) still fair to roll, given enough dice action to eliminate human variables, compared to a standard d20?

Comment: Yes. Every face is equally likely, no matter how the faces are numbered.

Comment: The reason the regular d20 is preferred over a spindown is not math related. It's that in real life there are imperfections in the dice that may make some hemispheres more likely. In a regular d20 this is not so bad since numbers are distributed so each hemisphere averages out. In spindown this isn't the case.